# Password generated from keyword

Tags: linux, database, ubuntu, passwords, keyword

I have some keywords and the respective passwords.
They are all in the same format, keyword is like 12345 and the password 00aa11bb. Given a long enough list os keywords and passwords is it possible to find the relation between the two?

Another thing is that two consecutive number are always the same.
For isntance 99px66rv.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a  machine learning topic.

You can treat your key-pass maps as training data. And use specify algorithm to let computer find the relationship between the map. You will end up with one 
polynomial, where the keywords could be input and passwords would be the output.

Comment: That would really need a big list of inputs in order to train.

Comment: And by the way any idea on how could I do that? Or any tutorials out there?